# What's the best way to notate a timed arpeggio with specific cutoff

Tags: notation, keyboard, arpeggios

[image: Two options for arpeggio notation]

This is a short excerpt (the upper hand part) from a piano piece I'm working on. I'd like this arpeggiated chord to end exactly when the trill start and to be played with the same hand. What is the best way to mark this for the performer?

Comment: Related answer: [How to notate specific-note harp glissando?](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/116243/70803).

Answer (score 2):

The second option is close, but the ties should not be open-ended, which means to let the notes continue to ring indefinitely. Instead:

> A notation convention allows consecutive notes joined by a beam to be tied over to a chord, even though this does not show accurate durations for every note. (Elaine Gould, *Behind Bars*, p. 133)

[image: Shortcut tied notation]

Gould explicitly advises against the nineteenth-century practice of double-stemmed notes and also the use of multiple ties for each note.

**Obsolete double-stemming**

[image: Double-stemmed notation]
(Image Source: Gould p. 133)

**Repeated tied notes**

[image: Fully tied notation]

Answer (score -1):

A phrase mark (a bow) over everything would make most players think to continue the arpeggio straight into the trill.

Comment: A keyboardist would assume it meant to play legato, not to retain each note. A pedal mark would also be incorrect, because of the change in timbre.

Comment: @Aaron - not if it's part of a chord. Guitar music is quite often written 'incorrectly', but we realise what's meant, and play it like it should have been written. Very often. And I'd probably pedal it anyway. Why wouldn't you if it all makes a chord?

Comment: On piano/keyboard, broken (arpeggiated) chords in which the notes are held versus not held are two completely different things and are notated to express that difference. I've never seen a (published) keyboard score in any genre that was notated in the way you describe.